# perl overload concatenation operator (".") problem

Tags: perl

Please, help me to understand, why reference count is growth on each concatenation?
I am returning the same object in overloaded sub, and expecting, that refcount will stay untouched. But, seems, that perl cloning and storing object somewhere every time. Why and how I can avoid this?

Also, I am expecting, that object will be destroyed just after exiting scope, but due to non-zero references count it destroyed only on global destruction phase. This is looks like a memory leak.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Devel::Refcount qw[refcount];

package AAA {
    use Devel::Refcount qw[refcount];

    use overload
      '.' => sub {
        print 'CONCAT, REFCOUNT: ', refcount( $_[0] ), "\n";

        # return AAA->new;
        return $_[0];
      },
      fallback => 0;

    sub new { return bless {}, $_[0] }

    sub DESTROY { print "DESTROY\n" }
}

print "--- start\n";

{
    my $o = AAA->new;

    my $s = '1' . ( '2' . ( '3' . ( '4' . ( '5' . $o ) ) ) );

    print "--- exit scope\n";
    print 'REFCOUNT: ', refcount($o), "\n";
}

print "--- end\n";

1;
```

**Tested under**

- perl 5.28.1 x64
- Devel::Refcount 0.10
- overload 1.30

**Output**

```
--- start
CONCAT, REFCOUNT: 1
CONCAT, REFCOUNT: 3
CONCAT, REFCOUNT: 5
CONCAT, REFCOUNT: 7
CONCAT, REFCOUNT: 9
--- exit scope
REFCOUNT: 6
--- end
DESTROY
```

Comment: For one, I copy-pasted your code and I get: 1--5 refcounts, then down to 2.  On v5.16

Comment: Can you please [edit] your post and add the version of Perl ( `perl -v` ) and the version of `Devel::Refcount` ( `perl -MDevel::Refcount -e "print Devel::Refcount->VERSION` ), and `overload` ( `perl -Moverload -e "print overload->VERSION"` ) you're using? On Perl 5.14 and using `Devel::Peek`, I can't reproduce the problem. I get `CONCAT, REFCOUNT 1` in all cases as output.

Comment: Yes, on perl 5.16 it adds 1 ref per iteration, on perl 5.28 - 2 refs / iteration. Very strange and unpredicted. On both perl versions refs count is increased that is not expected.

Comment: No repro on Perl 5.26 either. So it seems to be a rather recent change?

Comment: Replacing the use of Devel::Refcount with `    sub _refcount_pp
    {
       B::svref_2object( shift )->REFCNT;
    }
    *refcount = \&_refcount_pp;
`, I get the (expected) `CONCAT, REFCOUNT 1` (... 2, ... 3, ... 4, ... 5 ) and then 2. This doesn't look that bad to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just like the delayed `DESTROY` message, adding a weak ref to the object indicates a leak. The leak appears to have been introduced in Perl 5.28.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Scalar::Util qw( weaken );

package AAA {
    use overload
        '.' => sub { $_[0] },
        fallback => 0;

    sub new { return bless {}, $_[0] }

    sub DESTROY { print "DESTROY\n" }
}

my $w;
{
    my $o = AAA->new;
    weaken($w = $o);
    my $s = '1' . ( '2' . ( '3' . ( '4' . ( '5' . $o ) ) ) );
    print "Exiting scope...\n";
}

print "leak!\n" if defined($w);
#use Devel::Peek;
#Dump($w);

print "Global destruction...\n";
```

Output (before 5.28):

```
Exiting scope...
DESTROY
Global destruction...
```

Output (5.28.0 and 5.28.1):

```
Exiting scope...
leak!
Global destruction...
DESTROY
```

<strike>Please report using the `perlbug` command line utility.</strike>
<strike>The bug report can be found [here](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=133789).</strike>
It has been fixed in 5.30. It might be fixed in 5.28.2.

Comment: I have a hunch that this is a bug in the new [multiconcat](https://perldoc.pl/perl5280delta#Performance-Enhancements) optimization.

Comment: @zdm, Thanks for submitting the bug report. It can be found [here](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=133789).

Comment: Now fixed in blead with commit v5.29.7-70-g4e521aaf3e

Comment: This means it will be fixed in 5.30, and possibly 5.28.2